# Condition in an OUTER JOIN gives different result as in WHERE condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

While trying an `outer join` query I noticed that changing one condition from the `where` clause to the `join` clause changes the result. That surprised me but I simplified the tables and the query as below and now I think I understand but I would like to hear a solid explanation.

```
create table t0 (id int, b int);
create table t1 (id int, b int);
insert into t0 (id, b) values (1, 10), (2, 10);
insert into t1 (id, b) values (1, 2);

select t0.id, t0.b
from t0
left outer join t1 on 
    t0.id = t1.id
where
    t0.b = 10
    and
    t1.b = 2
;
 id | b  
----+----
  1 | 10
(1 row)
```

Now I move one of the conditions from the `where` to the `join` clause:

```
select t0.id, t0.b
from t0
left outer join t1 on 
    t0.id = t1.id
    and
    t1.b = 2
where 
    t0.b = 10
;
 id | b  
----+----
  1 | 10
  2 | 10
(2 rows)
```

Do you know how to write a straight reasoning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `on` condition of an `outer join` only determines if the `join` succeeds.  If the join fails, the joined columns are filled with `null`.

On the other hand, a `where` clause filters entire rows out of the result set.

To make this more clear, addd `t1.b` to the result set.  With `t1.b = 2` as a `where` condition, you get:

```
t0.id   t0.b   t1.id   t1.b
1       10     1       2
```

versus `t1.b = 2` as an `on` condition::

```
t0.id   t0.b   t1.id   t1.b
1       10     1       2
2       10     NULL    NULL
```

You can see why the `where` clause filters the second row out: `null = 2` is not true.

Comment: Or put the other way: a `WHERE` condition on the outer joined table turns the outer join into an inner join.